# Can I track the amount of time I spend on which websites on Safari (iOS and OSX)?

Tags: safari

I would like to get something like a report of how much times I spend on which websites on a daily, weekly and monthly basis.

For example statistics like, you spend 2 hours on twitter, 3 hours on facebook, and 3 hours on google in the last week.

I would like this kind of information, because I want to get more insights in my own behaviour.

I know there is Safari History. And I hope there are maybe applications that can analyze this history for me.

If not, could I maybe write a script that could this kind of information out of my Safari History?

I would like a solution for both iOS and OSX.

Comment: Why wouldn’t you just set up a web proxy and analyze the logs? Do you spend hours on iOS? Even so, a notebook or simple timer might work there better than trying to harvest data.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the app [Timing](https://timingapp.com).

> **Document-Based Tracking**
>
> Timing automatically tracks every app, document and website you use —
>   including the full file path or URL. This makes assigning time
>   tracking data much easier *and* more accurate.

I use it to track my computer time for the purposes of billing clients.

Comment: Thanks, this app looks great, I actually would also like something that works for iOS, it seems like this only works of OSX.

Comment: @Kasper is not possible to do this on iOS. The closest you get is the usage screen but that only shows it by app. Maybe with a jailbroken phone you could do it, but I wouldn't know the details.